# Como criar uma variável parametrizada?

Tags: c, array, declaração-de-variável

Em um exercício devo criar um número válido para cartões de crédito "Luhn’s Algorithm".

preciso criar uma variável parametrizada para evitar usar `if`, mas o código fica muito grande e eu quero reduzí-lo

Não posso usar *string*.

Segue qual seria a minha ideia para o variável parametrizada, caso exista.

```
# include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int sobra_number_cartao = 0;
    int contador = 0;
    int d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6, d7, d8, d9, d10, d11, d12, d13, d14, d15, d16;
    long number_cartao = get_long("Digite o número do seu cartão de crédito: \n");

    printf ("%li\n", number_cartao);

// Realiza a contagem da quantidade de números tem o cartão
while (number_cartao != 0)
{
    number_cartao = number_cartao / 10;
    contador ++;

/* Aqui eu quero criar uma variável parametrizada, exemplo: Vamos dizer que o valor da variável
"contador", seja 1, então quero escrever na d(1) = number_cartao.*/
    d(contador) = number_cartao;
}

printf ("Seu cartão tem %i números.\n", contador);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que deseja usar é o *array*. Mas deve tomar cuidado porque é fácil fazer besteira com ele em C. Você tem que ter certeza que armazenará a quantidade certa de dados. Se tentar gravar algo fora dele será aceito e corromperá a memória.

Aproveitei para resolver algumas outras questões, mas não fiz alguma validações, esse código está pronto para explodir em qualquer situação fora do normal. Nem falei que não se armazena número de cartão de crédito como um número, isto é um campo descritivo e deve ser um texto, mas resolvi ignorar esse erro conceitual e focar na questão, o que até seria mais fácil, só saiba que isso é errado. Algo assim (seria melhor usar um `for` no lugar do `while`):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int contador = 0;
    int d[16];
    printf("Digite o número do seu cartão de crédito:\n");
    long number_cartao;
    scanf("%ld", &number_cartao);
    printf("%ld\n", number_cartao);
    while (number_cartao != 0) {
        number_cartao /= 10;
        d[++contador] = number_cartao;
    }
    printf("Seu cartão tem %d números.\n", contador);
    printf("Item 0: %d", d[0]);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/p6ZkdS). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/awaucpsj-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/Simple.c).

Comment: Obrigado Maniero. Era isso mesmo que eu estava precisando. Valeu.